# Rails Devise thrown 302 error for non confirmed user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, rubygems

I have integrated the devise for coaches login in ROR site. It is working fine but when I tried to login through a user who is not confirmed yet it thrown 302 error. Here are the details of the code I have used:

```
1) Database Schema:

  create_table "coaches", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "first_name",             :limit => 20
    t.string   "last_name",              :limit => 20
    t.integer  "status",                 :limit => 2,   :default => 0
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.string   "email",                  :default => "", :null => false
    t.string   "encrypted_password",     :default => "", :null => false
    t.string   "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.integer  "sign_in_count",           :default => 0,  :null => false
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.string   "current_sign_in_ip"
    t.string   "last_sign_in_ip"
    t.string   "confirmation_token"
    t.datetime "confirmed_at"
    t.datetime "confirmation_sent_at"
    t.string   "unconfirmed_email" 
  end
```

2) Session Controller file:

```
class Coaches::SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
  layout :apply_devise_layout

  def create
    coach = Coach.where(:email => params[:coach][:email])[0]
    if coach.present? && !coach.confirmed?
        return render :json => {:success => false, :errors => t('devise.failure.unconfirmed')}  
    end
    resource = warden.authenticate!(:scope => resource_name, :recall => "#{controller_path}#failure")
    sign_in_and_redirect(resource_name, resource)
  end

  def sign_in_and_redirect(resource_or_scope, resource=nil)
    scope = Devise::Mapping.find_scope!(resource_or_scope)
    resource ||= resource_or_scope
    sign_in(scope, resource) unless warden.user(scope) == resource
    sign_out :admin
    sign_out :member
    return render :json => {:success => true,:msg=>t('devise.sessions.signed_in'),:sent_to=>resource.site_url || ''}
  end

  def failure
    return render :json => {:success => false, :errors => flash[:alert]}
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Coaches::SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
  def create
    coach = Coach.where(:email => params[:coach][:email]).first
    if coach.present? && !coach.confirmed?
      return render :json => {:success => false, :errors => t('devise.failure.unconfirmed')}    
    end
    if coach.present? 
        case coach.status
            when Coach::COACH_ACCOUNT_STATUS[:TRIAL_EXPIRED]
                return render :json => {:success => false, :errors => "Your trial has been expired, please <a href='/contact'>click here</a> to contact support team."} 
            when Coach::COACH_ACCOUNT_STATUS[:PREMIUM_EXPIRED]
                return render :json => {:success => false, :errors => "Your subcription has been expired, please <a href='/contact'>click here</a> to contact support team."}
            when Coach::COACH_ACCOUNT_STATUS[:DELETED]
                return render :json => {:success => false, :errors => "This account has been deleted, please <a href='/contact'>click here</a> to contact support team."}   
            when Coach::COACH_ACCOUNT_STATUS[:BLOCKED]
                return render :json => {:success => false, :errors => "This account has been suspended, please <a href='/contact'>click here</a> to contact support team."} 
        end
    end
    resource = warden.authenticate!(:scope => resource_name, :recall => "#{controller_path}#failure")
    sign_in_and_redirect(resource_name, resource)
  end

  def sign_in_and_redirect(resource_or_scope, resource=nil)
    session["warden.user.member.key"]=nil
    session["warden.user.admin.key"]=nil
    scope = Devise::Mapping.find_scope!(resource_or_scope)
    resource ||= resource_or_scope
    sign_in(scope, resource) unless warden.user(scope) == resource

    flash[:notice]=t('devise.sessions.signed_in');
    return render :json => {:success => true,:msg=>t('devise.sessions.signed_in'),:sent_to=>resource.site_url || ''}
  end

  def failure
    return render :json => {:success => false, :errors => flash[:alert]}
  end
end
```