# devise gem confirmation email sent 302 error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, devise-confirmable

i using devise gem user registration. But confirm email not sent. 302 error.

user.rb
add `:confirmable`

migration successful.

```
# config/environments/development.rb

config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'localhost:3000' } 
config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
config.action_mailer.default :charset => "utf-8"
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
       :address => 'smtp.gmail.com', 
       :port => 587, 
       :domain => "domain.com",
       :authentication => :plain,
       :user_name => "gmail@gmail.com",
       :password => "password"
}
```

Comment: possible duplication: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23577738/rails-devise-thrown-302-error-for-non-confirmed-user

Comment: Can you post your logs when a user signs up

Comment: error `Redirected to http://localhost:3000/users/sign_in
Completed 302 Found in 11ms (ActiveRecord: 3.0ms)`

and can generate confirmation_taken and save to database